# Parse R markdown file from blogdown before it is sent to pandoc

Tags: r-markdown, blogdown

I would like to rewrite the footnotes in all of my R markdown posts so they are rendered differently from the standard "place at bottom" used by markdown. For example, in a paragraph like

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.^[My footnote goes here] 
Nunc quis accumsan nunc. Ut urna orci, iaculis vel volutpat
```

I would want to wrap my footnote, "My footnote goes here", in custom css.

Is it possible to run an R script on the R markdown file *before* the R markdown document is parsed and send to pandoc? That would enable me to grep and search-and-replace the necessary items in the R markdown file.

Comment: Why not apply new CSS on the knitted HTML document?

Comment: Because the footnotes are added at the end of the document, and I'd like to include them as blurps where they are included in the document

Comment: If you add the script found [here](http://ignorethecode.net/blog/2010/04/20/footnotes/) to your RMarkdown and change the selector in line 9 to `$("a[class='footnote-ref']")`, then you get your blurps.

Comment: @MartinSchmelzer Yeah that might be a working solution. I'd prefer a non-javascript one though if possible. I've been looking at modify `R/build.R` but that runs *after* the page has been rendered. It might work, though.